# The fastest way to get current quadrant of an angle

Tags: algorithm, trigonometry

Firstly, this may sound very trivial, but currently I am creating a function getQuadrant(degree) for returning a quadrant from a given angle.

For instance, if degree is >= 0 and < 90, it will return 1. If degree is >= 90 and < 180, it will return 2. And so forth. This is very trivial. However, to be able to deal with degrees other than 0-360, I simply normalized those numbers to be in 0-360 degree range first, like this:

```
            while (angle > 360)
                angle = angle - 360;
            end

            while (angle < 0)
                angle = angle + 360;
            end
```

After that, I calculate. But to be frank, I hate using while statements like this. Are there other mathematical ways that can point out the quadrant of the angle in one go?

EDIT: I see that there are lots of good answers. Allow me to add "**which algorithm will be the fastest?**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of integer arithmetics:

```
angle = angle - (angle/360)*360;
if (angle < 0) angle = angle + 360;
```

The idea is, since `angle/360` is rounded down (`floor()`), `(angle/360)` gives you the `k` you need to do `alpha = beta + 360k`.

The second line is normalizing from [-359,-1] back to [1,359] if needed.

Comment: wait a minute... I am not sure if I follow. Aren't those (angle/360)*360 = angle ? And the end result for line 1 would always be 0 ?

Comment: OK, I got it. I was doing this in Matlab. But in a C language, this works perfectly, as angle/360 in integer operation will implicitly floor the number down. (I was not in C mode)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the modulo operation:

```
angle %= 360.0; // [0..360) if angle is positive, (-360..0] if negative
if (angle < 0) angle += 360.0; // Back to [0..360)
quadrant = (angle/90) % 4 + 1; // Quadrant
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(angle/90)%4+1
```

Assumptions:

1. `angle` is an integer
2. `angle` is positive
3. `/` is integer division

For negative angles you'll need some additional handling.

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged your question *trigonometry* so here's some trigonometry:

a) take `sin(theta)` and `cos(theta)` -- it doesn't matter how many (positive or negative) multiples of `360°` are included; `sin(400°)==sin(40°)==sin(-320°)` etc

b) if `sin(theta)>0` and `cos(theta)>0` theta is in quadrant 1

if `sin(theta)>0` and `cos(theta)<0` theta is in quadrant 2

and so on round the clock. Oh, and decide what to do at the 4 `corners` where `sin` and `cos` return `0`.